# How can I send multiple parameter in json response? (Laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel, object, web

I want take multiple values from the database using Ajax, for which I'm using the following code:

```
public function getParty($party_id){
            $party_info = Credits::where('party_id',$party_id)->get();
            foreach($party_info as $row)
            {
                $tariff_type=$row['vehicle_type'];
            }
            $tariff = Tariff::where('nozzel_type',$tariff_type)->get();
            $Party_info=compact($party_info);
            $Tariff =compact($tariff);
            $data =[$party_info,$tariff];
            return response()->json($data);
        }
```

In this code, I'm taking `$party_info` and `$tariff` and sending them in response, I found a solution to put both in a new object like I did into `$data`, to get these values in my view file I use the following code:

```
if(data){
                        $.each(data, function(key, value){
                          var p_amount = value.pending_amount;
                          var new_tariff = value.price;
                        document.getElementById('current_amount').value=new_tariff;
                        document.getElementById('pending_amount').value=p_amount;

                         });
}
```

If I send a single parameter through this method, it works, but with multiple parameters, it is notworking

Comment: Can you logged **data** to console and look at structure? Maybe you have extra layer in result

Comment: Also, you newer use `$Party_info` and  `$Tariff ` just only `[$party_info,$tariff]`

Answer (score 0):

return response()->json(['Party_info'=>$Party_info,'Tariff'=>$Tariff]);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's great that you want to help other users, but answers are expected to be more than just a line of code. Try to explain why your answer is correct to help the questioner learn.

Comment: @yakatz that is a great way of guiding someone, instead of those who just unvote the answer or a question